# Can't initialize ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, javafx, objectinputstream

I am setting a client/server application using JavaFX. To create the UI I used SceneBuilder.

I don't have any problems with the server class and with sending and receiving data as a simple line (readUTF, writeUTF). I decided to go a step further - sending and receiving objects between client and server. And here I have a problem. When I delete the line which initializes ObjectInputStream the program works well but if not the GUI doesn't turn on and if I close the server I get the exception below.

In short:
I can't initialize ObjectInputStream in initialize method because the GUI doesn't turn on.

```java
MainClient.class:

public class MainClient extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("page/client.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Initialize method in Controller class:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 7575);
            //out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Exception note:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/oska/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/cache/tmp/
Gtk-Message: 13:38:07.490: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2681)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at controller.ControllerClient.initialize(ControllerClient.java:43)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at MainClient.start(MainClient.java:11)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$424(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$404(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$402(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$403(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$208(GtkApplication.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Using `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` in a client-server scenario is a bad idea. `readObject()` is a know security vulnerability of Java and therefore should never be used with untrusted data (data potentially manipulated by an attacker). https://nytrosecurity.com/2018/05/30/understanding-java-deserialization/

Comment: What are you running on port 7575? It doesn't seem to be sending a raw Java Serialisation stream, or much at all - it looks like it just accepts and then closes the socket, sending little or, more likely, no data. (Also that'll be a resource leak - it's very easy to use try-with-resource.)